# Sinon test to check all methods were called in lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have my AWS lambda function like this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const myModel = exports.deps().myModel;
  return tools.checkPermission(event)
    .then((id) => myModel.create(JSON.parse(event.body), id))
    .then((campaign) =>
      tools.handleAPIResponse(
        callback,
        data,
        201,
        Object.assign({Location: event.path + '/' + data.id,}, tools.HEADERS)
      )
    ).catch(err => tools.handleAPIError(callback, err));
};
```

I am writing a test case using sinon.js just to check if all the methods in my lambda function were called by stubbing all the functions. like

```
myModel.create
tools.checkPermission
tools.handleAPIError
tools.handleAPIResopnse
```

I am stubbing and testing like this:

```
it('should call all functions ', () => {
 const event = {};

 createMyStub = sinon.stub(myModel, 'create');
 createMyStub.withArgs(sinon.match.any).returns(Promise.resolve('Hello'));

 const checkPermission = sinon.stub(tools, 'checkPermission');
 checkPermission.withArgs(sinon.match.any).returns(Promise.resolve('user'));

 const handleAPIResponse = sinon.stub(tools, 'handleAPIResponse');
 handleAPIResponse.withArgs(sinon.match.any).returns('Done');

 const callback = sinon.spy();

 API.handler(event, {}, callback);
 expect(checkPermission.called).to.be(true);
 expect(handleAPIResponse.called).to.be(true);
 expect(createMyStub.called).to.be(true);

 createMyStub.restore();
 checkPermission.restore();
 handleAPIResponse.restore();
});
```

But I am not getting expected results. Also how can I see content of the callback when I don't stub tools.handleAPIResponse, and expect an actual result in callback.

Comment: what is the result of your test?

Answer (score 0):

I spotted one crucial mistake in your test in this part

```
API.handler(event, {}, callback);
```

that function is async function so we must call it as promise such as

```
await API.handler(event, {}, callback);
```

or alternatively

```
API.handler(event, {}, callback).then(....)
```

I prefer the former approach. And also some part of tests can be improved like using `sinon.resolves` and `sinon.restore` as below:

```
it('should call all functions ', async () => { // specify `async`
  const event = {};

  createMyStub = sinon.stub(myModel, 'create');
  createMyStub.withArgs(sinon.match.any).resolves('hello'); // using `resolves`

  const checkPermission = sinon.stub(tools, 'checkPermission');
  checkPermission.withArgs(sinon.match.any).resolves('user')

  const handleAPIResponse = sinon.stub(tools, 'handleAPIResponse');
  handleAPIResponse.withArgs(sinon.match.any).returns('Done');

  const callback = sinon.spy();

  await API.handler(event, {}, callback); // specify `await`

  expect(checkPermission.called).to.be(true);
  expect(handleAPIResponse.called).to.be(true);
  expect(createMyStub.called).to.be(true);

  sinon.restore(); // this is sufficient in latest version of sinon, no need to restore on all methods
 });
```

Regarding your question to check on callback, maybe we can use `sinon.calledWith` e.g:

```
  expect(handleAPIResponse.calledWith(callback, ...).to.be(true);
```

Reference:

- https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.1.1/stubs/#stubresolvesvalue
- https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.1.1/spy-call/#spycallcalledwitharg1-arg2-

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried using this solution, but expect(handleAPIResponse.called).to.be(true);
  expect(createMyStub.called).to.be(true); are always returning false. Also, stubbing these functions in this test case is interfering with unit tests of actual tools object

Comment: @Bharthan what is `myModel` value from this line `createMyStub = sinon.stub(myModel, 'create');`?

Comment: `myModel` is a class object, that access database. So `myModel.create(JSON.parse(event.body), id)` creates a new record in the database. If it is successful it returns a promise with the `data` inserted as content.

Comment: @Bharthan cool. In your source, `myModel` comes from `const myModel = exports.deps().myModel;`, how about in the test? I didn't see it.